# React native on enter event

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm making a circular floating action button for react native. I'm activating the floating action button by using a long press (0.3 seconds). It will pop up all the mini floating action buttons. After that, I want to drag my finger to the mini floating action button I want to activate. When entering the mini floating action button (with the same touch as used for the long press) I want to show a 'hover state' (other background color and a tooltip).

Can anyone help me out with the last part? Using the same touch for activating the floating action buttons with a long press and selecting a mini action button?

[image: circular floating action buttons]

Thanks in advance!